# Implementing imagelightbox.js in HTML5/CSS3

Tags: html, image, css, gallery, lightbox

Very new to this, so sorry if I'm asking something really weird.

I'm trying to build a basic one-page responsive portfolio website in HTML5+CSS3 and want to use [this fluid/mobile friendly lightbox](http://osvaldas.info/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly) to display the galleries. However, I can't get it to work at all.

Here are the steps I followed: I downloaded+loaded in the latest version of jQuery and imagelightbox.js using the code provided on the imagelightbox website, like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="imagelightbox.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function()
    {
        $( 'a' ).imageLightbox();
    });
</script>
```

Then I tagged the images I want to display with the lightbox with the id "imagelightbox":

```
<a href="http://i.imgur.com/mBvaIk5.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/mBvaIk5.jpg" id="imagelightbox" /></a>
```

I turned the provided minimal CSS configuration from the website into "imagelightbox.css" and loaded that. I only changed the position from fixed to center, because in fixed my images weren't appearing at all.

```
#imagelightbox
{
    position: center;
    z-index: 9999;

    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

Nothing happens when I click the images though. I've tried to make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L23s5vc1/1/) of this. In the jsfiddle clicking the images does link to the full-view version, but in my case nothing happens at all unless I load the imagelightbox.js like this:

```
<script src="imagelightbox.js" type="txt/css" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

in which case clicking an image does link to its full-view version, but there's no lightbox to be found.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a conflict there. Remove IDs from imgs. The #imagelightbox rule is intended for the lightbox overlay not linked images. The init JS function processes all image links by default.

Comment: Omygod!!! I can't believe it but this fixed it. THANK YOU SO MUCH!! How did you know the ID wasn't needed for linked images? I thought the HTML instruction on the plugin's website put it behind a linked image as well...? Anyway, really really happy it works now ^_^

Comment: Well, it was kinda obvious from the CSS rule and IDs are used just for unique elements. Look at the demo page. Images are tagged according to the init JS function (data-imagelightbox in that example).

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things that i can think of why your image is not appearing at all...

1* there is no position: center property in css.... its position: absolute/static (default)/fixed/inherit/relative etc.. check this [w3schools link on css positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

2* was there any error in the browser console? ( right click->inspect element-> console on chrome /FF or F12 developer tools -> console in IE)

3* i have a feeling that if something is not loading then the path to that file whether it is the css or js file or even the image is wrong.

hope this helps

ADDENDUM:::: here is the simple code that i worked with...it seems fine for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="imagelightbox.js"></script>
<style>
    #imagelightbox
    {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9999;

        -ms-touch-action: none;
        touch-action: none;
    }
</style>
<script>

            $( function()
            {
                $( 'a' ).imageLightbox();
            });


</script>
</head>
<body>

        <a href="http://www.visioncritical.com/sites/default/files/blog-images/BLG_Andrew-G.-River-Sample_09.13.12.png"><img src="http://www.visioncritical.com/sites/default/files/blog-images/BLG_Andrew-G.-River-Sample_09.13.12.png" id="imagelightbox" ></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sai, thanks so much for responding! I should clarify that the images do load, but fail to display in the lightbox when clicked -- nothing happens on click. 1)Thanks, changed it to 'relative' but it has no effect. 2) Yes there are "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" errors for every image with the "imagelightbox" tag, but the local filepaths are correct. Other images without the tag (i.e. that I don't want to display in the lightbox) are not giving this error. Any ideas?

Comment: That error means that the file was not able to be located by the system.... now with respect to the webserver that you are running, are you giving the absolute path to the image or relative path to the image in your <a> tag? and keep the position: fixed. what fixed does in here is the plugin puts the image container right in the middle of the screen. I havent actually gone inside the plugin code itself but using position : relative could give you some problems.

Comment: Let me clarify about the fixed / relative difference. what i mean by my statement is that, when you have position: fixed , the image stays right in the center of the screen regardless of your scrolling. It gives you the image hovering above your rest of the page effect.when you give position: relative, the image will scroll up or down which is not what you are wanting to achieve ( i am assuming).

Comment: And also regarding the path to your image file, you need relative path to the file (from the root of your webserver). if your webserver is located in c:webserver/root folder then http://localhost refers to that folder. So if you have your images inside c:webserver/root/images folder, then your relative path is "/images". Again I tried the plugin on my personal server using both remote images and local images it works fine for me. Hope this helps . thanks

Comment: thanks again for your help! I checked again and it's only giving an error for filepaths I didn't put in yet. The images I'm trying to display are linked correctly (relative) and do display. If I change position to 'fixed', they disappear though. I understand what you're saying about problems with 'relative' though, so I put it on 'static' for now. I also found out the lightbox /does/ work, but opens all the way at the bottom of the page (so I missed it before!) instead of at the thumbnails' height. Pushing the position up in CSS doesn't seem to do much or be a good solution.

Comment: I understand if this is difficult to help with though (so many things, so chaotic lol). In any case thanks for your answers so far :)